# mdadm raid issues with (possibly out of date) and tries to mount raid6 as raid1

Tags: linux, raid, mdadm, software-raid

Some unknown hardware issue occurred that looks like it took all 4 hard drives offline occurred. wiggled some wires and hard drives are back (???). Now having raid issues.

Raid will not start

"/dev/md/1 assembled from 3 drives - not enough to start the array while not clean"

but troublingly it appears to be treating it as raid 1 when it is raid 6. A raid 6 array of 4 drives should be just fine with one whatever.

Any suggestions on trying to get this going again while retaining the data? any non destructive options first? I'm hesitant to force before i can figure out why it seems to believe its raid 1.

```
         mdadm --examine /dev/sd[dcba]3 | egrep 'Event|/dev'
        /dev/sda3:
                 Events : 395
        /dev/sdb3:
                 Events : 318
        /dev/sdc3:
                 Events : 396
        /dev/sdd3:
                 Events : 396
    
    So not that out of sync right?
    
    mdadm --assemble --scan -o -u 69d7ed4a:8bbcae7b:7fddfd36:6f1fcf16  -v
    mdadm: /dev/sdd3 is identified as a member of /dev/md/1, slot 1.
    mdadm: /dev/sdc3 is identified as a member of /dev/md/1, slot 2.
    mdadm: /dev/sdb3 is identified as a member of /dev/md/1, slot 3.
    mdadm: /dev/sda3 is identified as a member of /dev/md/1, slot 0.
    mdadm: added /dev/sda3 to /dev/md/1 as 0
    mdadm: added /dev/sdc3 to /dev/md/1 as 2
    mdadm: added /dev/sdb3 to /dev/md/1 as 3 (possibly out of date)
    mdadm: added /dev/sdd3 to /dev/md/1 as 1
    mdadm: /dev/md/1 assembled from 3 drives - not enough to start the array while not clean - consider --force.
```

examining the drives shows raid6 and that sdb3 is the only one that doesnt show a missing drive.

```
mdadm --examine /dev/sd[dcba]3
/dev/sda3:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.0
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : 69d7ed4a:8bbcae7b:7fddfd36:6f1fcf16
           Name : 1
  Creation Time : Sat Nov 24 17:11:48 2018
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 4

 Avail Dev Size : 15624915112 sectors (7.28 TiB 8.00 TB)
     Array Size : 15624915072 KiB (14.55 TiB 16.00 TB)
  Used Dev Size : 15624915072 sectors (7.28 TiB 8.00 TB)
   Super Offset : 15624915368 sectors
   Unused Space : before=0 sectors, after=296 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 53fb577d:03e1050b:3ab8b5b3:d5574384

    Update Time : Fri Jun 19 05:45:13 2020
       Checksum : 22c600bb - correct
         Events : 395

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 64K

   Device Role : Active device 0
   Array State : AAA. ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
/dev/sdb3:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.0
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : 69d7ed4a:8bbcae7b:7fddfd36:6f1fcf16
           Name : 1
  Creation Time : Sat Nov 24 17:11:48 2018
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 4

 Avail Dev Size : 15624915112 sectors (7.28 TiB 8.00 TB)
     Array Size : 15624915072 KiB (14.55 TiB 16.00 TB)
  Used Dev Size : 15624915072 sectors (7.28 TiB 8.00 TB)
   Super Offset : 15624915368 sectors
   Unused Space : before=0 sectors, after=296 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : ac920534:e5bc15e4:b2472221:ce16aa24

    Update Time : Fri Jun 19 05:32:52 2020
       Checksum : c05abf36 - correct
         Events : 318

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 64K

   Device Role : Active device 3
   Array State : AAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
/dev/sdc3:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.0
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : 69d7ed4a:8bbcae7b:7fddfd36:6f1fcf16
           Name : 1
  Creation Time : Sat Nov 24 17:11:48 2018
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 4

 Avail Dev Size : 15624915112 sectors (7.28 TiB 8.00 TB)
     Array Size : 15624915072 KiB (14.55 TiB 16.00 TB)
  Used Dev Size : 15624915072 sectors (7.28 TiB 8.00 TB)
   Super Offset : 15624915368 sectors
   Unused Space : before=0 sectors, after=296 sectors
          State : active
    Device UUID : 665a7028:041ce9d4:45396f7e:e9f45574

    Update Time : Fri Jun 19 05:45:18 2020
       Checksum : 528db8f6 - correct
         Events : 396

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 64K

   Device Role : Active device 2
   Array State : AAA. ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
/dev/sdd3:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.0
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : 69d7ed4a:8bbcae7b:7fddfd36:6f1fcf16
           Name : 1
  Creation Time : Sat Nov 24 17:11:48 2018
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 4

 Avail Dev Size : 15624915112 sectors (7.28 TiB 8.00 TB)
     Array Size : 15624915072 KiB (14.55 TiB 16.00 TB)
  Used Dev Size : 15624915072 sectors (7.28 TiB 8.00 TB)
   Super Offset : 15624915368 sectors
   Unused Space : before=0 sectors, after=296 sectors
          State : active
    Device UUID : 9b1ebb07:6cf51bf4:b6a52bd7:e7beedf9

    Update Time : Fri Jun 19 05:45:18 2020
       Checksum : 2f5f8d02 - correct
         Events : 396

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 64K

   Device Role : Active device 1
   Array State : AAA. ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
```

checked all drives with smartctl and don't see any issues.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any evidence that mdadm is trying to use RAID 1.

What I do see is mdadm trying to start a RAID 6, finding one disk out of date and two missing, and quite reasonably refusing to assemble it.

Given you've one out of date disk and it's RAID 6 you're probably not going to be able to rely on anything from this collection. Time to restore from your backup if you have one.